# Attempting to copy string from user-input in .asm

Tags: assembly, masm

I'm attempting to write an assembly program to copy a string given by the user and output it back. However, every time I test it, it outputs random characters instead of what's given.

For example:

```
Enter string: Hello
Copy of your string: --
```

This is the code I have working so far, and I'm sure it has something to do with the offset. I just have no idea what.

```
cr      EQU     0dh     ; carriage return character
Lf      EQU     0ah     ; line feed

.DATA           

inputPrompt     BYTE    "Enter string:   ", 0
string          BYTE    20 DUP (?)
msg_copy        BYTE    cr, Lf, "Copy of your string: "
copy            BYTE    11 DUP (?)
                BYTE    cr, Lf, 0


.CODE                           ; start of main program code
_start:
    output  inputPrompt         ; prompt for string
    input   string, 20          ; read ASCII characters
    mov     copy, al            ; copy to output byte
    output  msg_copy            ; output message and string copy
    INVOKE  ExitProcess, 0      ; exit with return code 0

PUBLIC _start                   ; make entry point public

END                             ; end of source code
```

Comment: Where do you actually copy the string? I see the `mov     copy, al`, but that's just one byte (and you haven't made clear what `al` contains at that point).

Comment: I added `mov al, string` in-between the `input` and `mov copy, al` lines. Now it will output the first letter of each string, but for any inputs longer than one character it drops everything but the first character

Comment: `al` is an 8-bit register. It can hold exactly _one_ character. Is that somewhat less than you expected?

Comment: Yep, that solved that problem. Now all that's left is dealing with a "Constant value too large" error in `inputPrompt` and `msg_copy`